# How to display a column dynamically from javascript array dynamically inside Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery

I have got a local JSON flat DataSource as shown below

```
var dataSet = [
    [
        "481.55",
        "10.40"

    ],
    [
        "561.30",
        "-2.55"

    ],
    [
        "368.20",
        "33.45"

    ]

];
```

And i am using Jquery Datatables to display Data in tabular format this way

```
 $(function()
  {

      $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Price" },
            { "title": "Volume" }


        ]
    } );   

  })
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/9/

With this the data is shown in this way

**

```
Price   Volume
368.20  33.45
481.55  10.40
561.30  -2.55
```

**

I have got a javascript array as shown below where the first value refers to first value of the dataSet array and so on

```
var array_names =['ONE','TWO','THREE'];
```

My question is , Is it possible to display One more additional column Name in Jquery Datatables so that it looks like this

```
Name Price   Volume
ONE     368.20  33.45
TWO     481.55  10.40
THREE     561.30  -2.55
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery datatables doesn't support adding columns dynamically but there is a feasibility to hide/filter the column if you don't want it. 
As per my knowledge, this can be achieved in 2 ways

1. Prepare the dataset(with 3 column values) and then
   initialize the datatable with the dataset.
2. create a table with 3 column headers in the view and fill the table with content on page load or fill the datatable through the ajax call.

Comment: I cannot go for the first Option as the dataset values will be returned from a backend server and i an't modify that . Could you please elaborate the second option a sample jsfiddle if you don't mind .

Comment: With this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/13/ , i am always getting only the first value from the array

Comment: I have changed the dataSet a bit. this might help you. Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshBoora/ktdj3u9r/